# A universal wave form and the observable universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observable-universe

This may have been on the table before but I don't find such a question directly.

If we started to approach the concept of a universal wave function, how would we consider the matter outside the observable universe?

Would that be part of the range or scope of the wave form?

Edit: The concept would be less impressive and less general if it had to be represented anew for every point in space.

Comment: [Many-worlds FAQ](https://www.hedweb.com/manworld.htm#what), everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your talking about the Hartle-Hawking wavefunction of the Universe, then their solution was to only consider closed universes (both in space and time). So that means there is only a finite volume to consider. There would not be anything else outside it.

Personally, I think you could probably construct a theory limited to the visible portion of the Universe, but that is not the common consensus.

Comment: I think, he is not talking about closed or open, but about “outside” of our observable part of the universe. Even in a closed universe there may be regions that will never be observable by us because of the light speed limit and expansion (right?)

Comment: That is what I meant although I must admit I didn't think of open or  closed versions.